# "wmode=direct" Behavior In Older Browsers And Flash Versions

Tags: html, flash, wmode

I want to apply `wmode=direct` to flash objects on my page.
What are the behaviour it will accomplish in older browsers (IE6,IE7,etc.)?
Or the older versions of Flash Player?
Does the parameter behave as default(`window`) or `transparent`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation doesn't explicitly say, but as per [Flash OBJECT and EMBED tag attributes](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html#main_BrowserSupportForWmodes):

> Explicit layering control is only supported with some modern browsers (see table below). In other browsers, the SWF content always appears above other HTML elements.

This sounds like `opaque`:

> The SWF file is opaque and hides everything layered behind it on the page

Comment: The default behavior is "window", meaning nothing can appear over the flash. With opaque you can still z-index the flash, it just won't be transparent.